# How can I :find a file when opening vim from the command line?

Tags: vim

I have my vim nicely set up with `&path` to help me find files using only the name:

```
cd $PROJECT
vim

:fi foo.c             -> loads "$PROJECT/path/to/foo.c"
```

How can I get that same behavior when specifying files on the command line? That is, I want to do this:

```
cd $PROJECT
vim foo.c             -> loads "$PROJECT/path/to/foo.c"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use your shell's `find`? Something like this (from the command line):

```
>vim $(find foo.c)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to locate the file. If I think about it, I usually know exactly where it is. I'm just trying to be lazy, and not have to type anything more than I must.

Comment: Does this not do what you want then? It loads vim with the results of the find - basically the same as loading vim, then running your find command from inside vim. I'm not sure how much shorter it can be.

Comment: No, it doesn't do what I want: specifically, allow me to type `vim foo.c` and get the file.

Comment: OK. In that case you could write a function to detect whether the file exists and if not, try to find it. However that has the problem of needing to type the filename exactly. I think it would be much easier and quicker to use some kind of fuzzy finder like fzf: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that someone hasn't already written this. Or, surprised that google failed to find it for me.

Anyway, I am under the constraint that a plugin has to run, first, in order to set `&path` to the values I need (vim-localrc plugin). My first attempt, using an `autocmd BufNew` failed because `&path` still had its default value.

I came up with this hack. It doesn't support multiple buffers, etc., but I figure I'll add that when I get mad about needing it:

```
function! Find_if_not_exist(path)
    if ! filereadable(a:path)
        exe ":find ".a:path
    endif
endfunction
autocmd VimEnter * call Find_if_not_exist(expand('<afile>'))
```

Comment: "I'm surprised that someone hasn't already written this." Maybe because it's not needed to begin with?

Comment: "You're a funny guy, Sully. I like you."

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, `:fi` is not a shortcut for `:find`. It's a shortcut for `:file`, which is **very** different from `:find`.

> How can I get that same behavior when specifying files on the command line?

You could tell Vim to execute `:find foo.c` at startup with:

```
$ vim +find\ foo.c
```